# How to test api that uses django-rest-auth token authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-rest-auth, django-tests

I am using django-rest-auth for authentication and using token provided by it for authorization. I have use some permission_class also provided by django-rest.
I have folloging in views.py before my each methods.

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication))
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
```

How can I authenticate to access that methods inside views.py while testing those api. Because without authentication it gives 403 forbidden.
How can I mock the authentication in test.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need create a user and a token for this user,
after that create a `django.test.Client` using token as header.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token                                  

from django.test import Client 

self.user = Usuario.objects.create_user(                                   
    nome='test',                                                                                   
    email='test@email.com',                                                                   
    password='test',                                                    
)                                                                             
token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=self.user)                
self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
```

Then you can make any request using this authenticated client.

`self.client.get('url')`

Comment: It didn't work for me!